# azure CLI `func new` gives error `Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value')`

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, azure-cli

The Azure CLI command

`func new` kept producing the same error:

`One or more errors occurred. (Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value'))`

What causes this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to delete `"extensionBundle"` block from the `host.json` - issue seems to be related to the extension bundle installation on windows and simple removing this reference to them fixes the problem

**Update**

This however has a consequence that extension bindings that you might later need during `func start` will not be found and hence give errors. So you might need to add extensionBundle back afterwards.

Strangely this process of deleting it for `func new` command and adding it back before `func start` works.